# SVG Pan only when zoomed, bigger than viewport

Tags: javascript, svg, svgpanzoom

**Expected Outcome**: Unable to pan SVG if it is not zoomed and SVG remains centered. When zoomed, allow panning to its boundaries.

**Problem**:

Using this solution [How to only allow pan within the bounds of the original SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912619/how-to-only-allow-pan-within-the-bounds-of-the-original-svg), it still allows you to pan when SVG is not zoomed and when zoomed doesn't allow panning to all boundaries

Using this solution [How to only allow pan within the bounds of the original SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912619/how-to-only-allow-pan-within-the-bounds-of-the-original-svg#comment76631256_38125080), panning while zoomed works as expected but when the SVG is not zoomed, once I try to pan it snaps to the right and to the bottom instead of remaining centered.

```
let beforePan

beforePan = function (oldPan, newPan) {
  let stopHorizontal = false,
    stopVertical = false,
    gutterWidth = this.getSizes().width,
    gutterHeight = this.getSizes().height,
    // Computed variables
    sizes = this.getSizes(),
    leftLimit = -((sizes.viewBox.x + sizes.viewBox.width) * sizes.realZoom) + gutterWidth,
    rightLimit = sizes.width - gutterWidth - (sizes.viewBox.x * sizes.realZoom),
    topLimit = -((sizes.viewBox.y + sizes.viewBox.height) * sizes.realZoom) + gutterHeight,
    bottomLimit = sizes.height - gutterHeight - (sizes.viewBox.y * sizes.realZoom)

  customPan = {}
  customPan.x = Math.max(leftLimit, Math.min(rightLimit, newPan.x))
  customPan.y = Math.max(topLimit, Math.min(bottomLimit, newPan.y))
  
  return customPan
}

let panZoomController = svgPanZoom('#map', {
  fit: 1,
  center: true,
  minZoom: 1,
  zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.5,
  beforePan: beforePan
});
```

The SVG (map) is inside a content div which is inside a wrapper div:

```
.wrapper {
    margin: auto;
}

.content {
    background-color: silver;
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0 0 0 0;
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours and tries to make it work using only one calculation I decided to use a different calculation when the SVG was smaller than the viewport (no panning allowed). Code below:

```
beforePan = function (oldPan, newPan) {
  let stopHorizontal = false,
    stopVertical = false,
    sizes = this.getSizes(),
    customPan = {}

  if (sizes.viewBox.width * sizes.realZoom < sizes.width || sizes.viewBox.height * sizes.realZoom < sizes.height) {
    customPan.x = (window.visualViewport.width - (sizes.viewBox.width * sizes.realZoom)) / 2
    customPan.y = (window.visualViewport.height - (sizes.viewBox.height * sizes.realZoom)) / 2
    console.log(sizes.viewBox.width)
  } else {
    let gutterWidth = sizes.width,
    gutterHeight = sizes.height,
    leftLimit = -((sizes.viewBox.x + sizes.viewBox.width) * sizes.realZoom) + gutterWidth,
    rightLimit = sizes.width - gutterWidth - (sizes.viewBox.x * sizes.realZoom),
    topLimit = -((sizes.viewBox.y + sizes.viewBox.height) * sizes.realZoom) + gutterHeight,
    bottomLimit = sizes.height - gutterHeight - (sizes.viewBox.y * sizes.realZoom)

    customPan.x = Math.max(leftLimit, Math.min(rightLimit, newPan.x))
    customPan.y = Math.max(topLimit, Math.min(bottomLimit, newPan.y))
  }

  return customPan
}
```